# How to get the current user object in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I am proficient in Drupal 7 where I get the current user object from `global $user`, but how do I get it in Drupal 8 ?

Comment: Maybe this one would help you? -> https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146308/access-user-fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use following code to get the current user object in Drupal 8:
`$user = \Drupal::currentUser();`

Comment: Thanks Vipin. Is there way to get the user Id directly by using any function or anything global variable.

Comment: Yes Vikas. use $ownerId = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();

Answer (score 10):

One liner way to get a *full* drupal user object for the current active user :

```
$account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
```

Why not just `Drupal::currentUser()` ? Because most of the time it won't be sufficient as you'll need a fully loaded user object while it's not :

- [`\Drupal::currentUser()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AcurrentUser/8.6.x) returns an [`AccountProxyInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountProxyInterface.php/interface/AccountProxyInterface/8.6.x).
- [`\Drupal\user\Entity\User::load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityBase.php/function/EntityBase%3A%3Aload/8.7.x) actually returns a [user entity object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserInterface.php/interface/UserInterface/8.7.x).

Answer (score 2):

According to [entity api](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/working-with-the-entity-api), we should not use User::load. Instead, use entityTypeManager like so :

```
$user_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
$user_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load($user_id);
```

Comment: Per the Entity API documentation that you just linked, one should "Avoid using the static Entity::load() method in object oriented code. Instead use dependency injection to inject the entity type manager and load the entity with $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage($entity_type)->load($entity_id)." It is worth noting that it is fine to use the static Entity::load() method in other circumstances where you wouldn't be using dependency injection, though, such as a .module file etc.

Comment: Also, the code you shared above does NOT use dependency injection, as recommended by the Entity API, which defeats the purpose of preferring $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage($entity_type)->load($entity_id) over the static Entity::load() method.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @kenS, you're right about that dependency injection. Nevertheless, my answer has the advantage of not having to include 'use Drupal\user\Entity\User;' at the top of your php file.

Comment: True enough. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57026412/10146245 likewise does not require a use statement and IMO is easier code to write and to read, so personally that's what I'd prefer when not using dependency injection. But the reason for my downvote is not your code, which looks fine and is a valid way to get the current user, but because your statement above the code ("According to entity api, we should not use User::load. Instead, use entityTypeManager...") is inaccurate/misleading in the manner that I pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = \Drupal::currentUser();
```

To get the current userID you can use :

```
$user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
```